# how to fix The bottom bar disappears when transferring from notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, navigator

how to fix The bottom bar disappears when transferring from notification in flutter
i used navigatorKey to redirect from notification :

```
navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(route);
```

Everything works as expected
Only when redirect from notification payload the bottom bar disappear
Please help ..

i used navigator.of(context) but return error used null operator